# Customize Existing Button MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: button, visual-studio-2008, dynamics-crm, ribbon

I am pretty new at MS Dynamics CRM and trying to learn all development process by myself.
I customized a solution into MS Dynamics CRM by using the Solutions segments and published it. But there wasn't any development process. I want to change the existing button's codes. For example I want write a Select statement into 'New' button. Also I want to create a custom button and write some sample codes into it. How can I do that? I already download and install Ribbon Workbench but it doesn't give me these options (writing code samples etc.).

Should we do this into Visual Studio 2008? If we do how can I add the solution's code into there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to be using JScript in ribbon buttons.  There are a lot of [samples on the web](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/using-javascript-in-a-custom-button-in-crm-2011/) for doing this.  You should use a ribbon editor to speed things up.

The only tricky part is referencing your WebResource from the ribbon.  You'll want to use the $webresource: notation as [this example shows](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/01/18/how-to-view-ribbon-definitions-in-crm-2011-3/).  You may want to check out the [Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/).